# Using renv in my project. But why deleting package from binary cache will brake R script execution?

Tags: r, rscript, renv

I am confused with all renv thing.
From my understanding there are should be just 2 environments:

```
global or system (C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\library)
```

and user:

```
(C:\Users\myusername\Documents\R\myproject\renv\library\R-4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32)
```

So if I want isolate my project packages I need to install them into renv of my project (C:\Users\myusername\Documents\R\DUAL Automations\renv\library\R-4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Running .libPaths() gives me the below output:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/myusername/Documents/R/myproject/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
[2] "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/sandbox/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1e360f03"
```

I understand the [1] is my project renv.

But what about [2]? Who set this path? Why do I have packages in it?

I also discovered another locations with packages in it, and the most important, if I delete a package from this location my R script won't execute!

C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\R\cache\R\renv\binary\R-4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\repository

So my questions are:

1. why .libPaths()  gives me this location [2] `"C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/sandbox/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1e360f03"?`
   Can I change it or remove it?
2. why deleting package from  `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\R\cache\R\renv\binary\R-4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32\repository`  will brake my R script even though I have renv with same package in it? Does it mean I am not using renv?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why they do it that way, but if you look at the contents of your `[2]`, you'll see that it contains all of the base packages installed in the original installation of R (e.g., `base`, `boot`, `compiler`, `stats`, `tools`, `utils`, all that are "base R"). So for your "who" question, it's `renv`. For "why do I have packages in it", it's a mimicry of `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/library` or such (on linux, the contents of it are symlinks to the real dirs). I suggest you could change your `[2]` to point to the original `C:/Program Files/...` dir without consequence, untested.

Comment: Said differently you should _always_ have at least two directories in `.libPaths()`: the "base" directory, whether or not it is the original or (in this case) a mockup of it; and your "personal" directory for packages, which may be global or when using `renv` a directory within your project folder.